# CSS - Hide first <tr> with Class

Tags: css, class, html-table, row

I need to hide the first tr.snip row

Why this CSS doesnt work?

```
.table tr.snip:first-child {
    display:none!important;

}
```

html

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr class="snip">...</tr>
    <tr class="snip">...</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `.snip:first-child`, you are looking for something that both has the `snip` class and is the first child of its parent. In your table, the first row with the `snip` class is the third child, so the selector doesn't work.

Directly selecting things the way you're trying to won't be possible until selectors level 4 comes out, so at the moment your best bet is to try to combine sibling selectors (`+` and `~`) with pseudo selectors. What exactly you do depends on how complicated your use case is.

The simplest solution for your example would be:

```
tr + tr.snip {
  display: none;
}
```

If necessary, you could also try something like:

```
tr:not(.snip) + tr.snip {
  display: none;
}
```

Or you could do it in reverse:

```
tr.snip {
  display: none;
}
tr.snip + tr.snip {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Or (if this is more appropriate):

```
tr.snip {
  display: none;
}
tr.snip ~ tr {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to select a `tr.snip` that is **ALSO** the `first child` of its parent. The `tr.snip` you are trying to hide is the second child of its parent, so it doesn't match the `CSS` selector.

Also, don't forget to put your content inside `td`, like this:

```
<tr class="snip"><td>...</td></tr>
```